# How to open an URL using fromHTML?

Tags: java, android, html, webview, fromhtml

I want to open `url` using `Html.fromHtml()`also the particular text between tags should be green in color and not underline.

How can I do that right now I'm doing like this:

```
consent = consent.replace("<clickable>", "<a href=\"https://www.google.com/\"").replace("</clickable>", "</a>");
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    consentCheck.setText(Html.fromHtml(consent, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    consentCheck.setText(Html.fromHtml(consent));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

To change color :

```
String blue = "this is blue";
SpannableString blueSpannable = new SpannableString(blue);
blueSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, blue.length(), 0);
builder.append(blueSpannable);

mTextView.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: yes see my yesterdays question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026982/how-to-make-text-underline-and-remove-text-at-the-same-time